# OpenNMS Heartbeat monitor

Tags: opennms

I'm new to OpenNMS and I'm finding it hard to figure out what I should do to monitor my python processes.

What I would like to do is to have each of my python processes issue SNMP trap heartbeats and to use OpenNMS to monitor these. I can't however find any information showing easy examples of how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I never used net-snmp for sending traps.
But it seems that net-snmp has a good [tutorial](http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmptrap.html).
If your trap has reached the ONMS server, you have to define this trap in an [event definition file].

Do you know the [send-event] script? It directly creates an event in ONMS. Unfortunately you have to configure you the [eventd] to allow events from somewhere else than localhost. It might be complicated in a big environment.

To be honest, I would prefer the snmptrap solution. Net-snmp is available on nearly every operating system per default (repositories).

BUT: Depending on how your processes are build, you could use the [HostResourceSwRunMonitor].

Maybe you should give some more information about your scenario.

Sorry: I can't send more than 2 links because of my reputation.

**Additional to the SNMPTRAP solution**:
Make sure there's an event defined that will match the trap, then

```
snmptrap -v2c -c <community> <opennms host> <sysUpTime in timeticks> <trap OID> <varbind> <varbind type> <varbind value>
```

e.g.,

```
snmptrap -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1854239596 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.14.4.0.5 1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.3.0 a 192.168.100.20 1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.14.4.1.1 s '01/09/2017 19:00:48 vte1 VT: DLm454E: Device 704A volume 465172 not found'
```

And finally this one:
https://github.com/opennms-forge/snmptrap-tester

Comment: [send-event]: https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/Send-event.pl

[eventd]: https://github.com/OpenNMS/opennms/blob/master/opennms-base-assembly/src/main/filtered/etc/eventd-configuration.xml

[HostResourceSwRunMonitor]: https://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/18.0.3/guide-admin/guide-admin.html#_hostresourceswrunmonitor